# How to select Omega character in arcade mode (against computer)?

Tags: ultra-street-fighter-iv

I am able to play with Omega (v 1.04 patch) character in training mode but I am not able to select it while playing against computer in arcade mode.

Can some one please help me? How to select omega(v 1.04 patch) character  while playing against computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to use the Omega version of characters in arcade mode.

This is due to the fact that Omega characters (intentionally) break the game balance and as such breaks all the achievements in place for Arcade mode.

Comment: even with some kind of hack ... like at some i place read by just copying some files the move set will change ... will it not possible like tht ?